# How to remove part of a string?

Tags: javascript, string

Let’s say I have `test_23` and I want to remove `test_`.

How do I do that?

The prefix before `_` can change.

Comment: maybe you should take a look to [Regular Expressions in JavaScript](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)

Answer (score 190, accepted):

My favourite way of doing this is "splitting and popping":

```
var str = "test_23";
alert(str.split("_").pop());
// -> 23

var str2 = "adifferenttest_153";
alert(str2.split("_").pop());
// -> 153
```

[*split()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) splits a string  into an array of strings using a specified separator string.
[*pop()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) removes the last element from an array and returns that element.

Comment: The C programmer in me cringes at the number of objects created and destroyed on this simple split/pop operation :) Probably: an array, 2 string, another array, another string.

Comment: @xgbi: yeah, JavaScript and C developers have rather different philosophies, though ;-)

Comment: You could add to your answer the possibility of using `alert(str.split("_")[1]);` since `.split` creates an array with two elements, `[0]` being before the `"_"` and `[1]` after. This was actually what I was looking for, but your answer helped me get there^^

Comment: @FernandoSilva Then, say if there were two "_" or more, we'd get 3 item array and be able to use/delete the third one too, right? BTW, +1. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @TheLightSabrix take a look at it working, it's much easier than trying to explain it in text. http://jsbin.com/keleguzacu/edit?js,console

Comment: Don't work if string contains two underlines, but want to split only till first one!

Answer (score 84):

If you want to **remove** part of string

```
let str = "try_me";
str.replace("try_", "");
// me
```

If you want to **replace** part of string

```
let str = "try_me";
str.replace("try_", "test_");
// test_me
```

Comment: If you want to replace all matches, use `str.replaceAll("try_", "");`

Answer (score 52):

Assuming your string always starts with `'test_'`:

```
var str = 'test_23';
alert(str.substring('test_'.length));
```

Comment: what if it doesn't start with test?

Comment: use replace but that doesn't work if there are multiple occurences. 
str.replace("test_", ""); will return a new string where all occurences of "test_" are removed, so if only one occurence is guaranteed, then it should be fine. However, if there are multiple, I would use 
str = 
str.substring(0, str.indexOf("test_)" + 
str.substring(str.indexOf("test_") + 5, str.length); I know this is an old post but, if anyone comes across it, might help at least one person out there somewhere.

Answer (score 23):

Easiest way I think is:

```
var s = yourString.replace(/.*_/g,"_");
```

Answer (score 12):

```
string = "test_1234";
alert(string.substring(string.indexOf('_')+1));
```

It even works if the string has no underscore.  Try it at http://jsbin.com/

Comment: This has less overhead, but more code than Andy E's answer.  Both work, but I prefer this method.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let text = 'test_23';
console.log(text.substring(text.indexOf('_') + 1));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the slice() string method to remove the begining and end of a string

```js
const str = 'outMeNo';

const withoutFirstAndLast = str.slice(3, -2);
console.log(withoutFirstAndLast);// output-->  'Me'
```