# how to remove a specific string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have these links in a gallery:

```
<div id="mygallery">
<ul>
<li><a href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8484/824625656895_5e5645636c50d_s.jpg">image 1</a></li>
<li><a href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8684/824625654348_5e5546fdcc50d_s.jpg">image 2</a></li>
<li><a href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8474/824623123897_f53s3afs6c50d_s.jpg">image 3</a></li>
<li><a href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8984/824625656856_5asdfet656655_s.jpg">image 4</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

How can I remove the "_s" from them? So I end up with

```
<div id="mygallery">
<ul>
<li><a href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8484/824625656895_5e5645636c50d.jpg">image 1</a></li>
<li><a href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8684/824625654348_5e5546fdcc50d.jpg">image 2</a></li>
<li><a href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8474/824623123897_f53s3afs6c50d.jpg">image 3</a></li>
<li><a href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8984/824625656856_5asdfet656655.jpg">image 4</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

[Live Copy](http://jsfiddle.net/xKyqY/1/)

Comment: you can use replace() function in javascript

Comment: have you tried anything first?

Comment: You need to specify what options you have available. It could be done using powershell, batch file, vbscript, regular expression replace in a text editor and more besides. What is it that you are trying to do? Is this part of a program, if so what language? This is way too open a question.

Comment: see this link:
[remove part of string][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568921/how-to-remove-part-of-a-string

Comment: here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xKyqY/1/

Answer (score 2):

**See update below**

I'll make the massive assumption that you have these strings in an array or something.

If so:

```
var index;
for (index = 0; index < theArray.length; ++index) {
    theArray[index] = theArray[index].replace("_s.jpg", ".jpg");
}
```

When you give it a string to search for, `replace` will replace the first occurrence of that string with the replacement string you give it. I did `"_s.jpg"` (replacing with `".jpg"`) rather than just `"_s"` out of paranoia, in case `"_s"` might appear earlier.

---

Sure enough, more information completely changes the question.

```
​$("a").each(function() {
    this.href = this.href.replace("_s.jpg", ".jpg");
});​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xKyqY/2/)

Comment: here is My fiddle Sir http://jsfiddle.net/xKyqY/1/

Comment: this works, but can it be for that particular div only, it might affect others

Comment: @FrancisAlvinTan: Of course it can: `$("selector for the div").find("a").each(...)`. More: http://api.jquery.com

Comment: @FrancisAlvinTan: No worries.

Answer (score 0):

Assuing that `string` is the url.

```
string = string.replace("_s", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

May be try with this for all kind of formats

```
str.replace('_s.', '.');
```