# How to force jQuery to change CSS value itself, instead of adding inline styles?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Developing my own grid system, I decided to use jQuery instead of adding classes for every width or height.
I found the code below from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33351385/javascript-dynamically-set-width-based-on-number-in-class-name) to change the width of divs with jQuery, based on their classname:

```
$("[class*='tul-']").each(function(){
    $(this).css("width", 100 / $(this).attr("class").substring(4,5) + "%");
});
```

So, something like: `<div class="tul-5"></div>` should have a `100 / 5 + "%" = 20%` width.

The problem is that jQuery adds *inline-css* instead of changing the value of *width* property in class `(tul-5)` itself. The `<div class="tul-5"></div>` becomes `<div class="tul-5" style="width: 20%"></div>`.
What I want is:

```
tul-5 {
    width: 20%; /*change this*/
}
```

I want to get rid of inline-css because of SEO and the mess it makes.

**Things I tried:**

I tried creating classes with a default width size, but no luck:

```
.tul-1, .tul-2, .tul-3 {
    width: 50px;
}
```

I've also tried pure Js code from the page mentioned above, but it also adds inline-css.

P.S.: I haven't declared any classes starting with `tul`.

Comment: If you're developing your own grid system you don't need javascript. This can be done with SASS or LESS. Look how it's implemented in Bootstrap or Material-UI, there are source files in sass and less

Comment: What does inline css have to do with SEO?

Comment: can you share complete code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How modify a property of external CSS file using jQuery / Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33784443/how-modify-a-property-of-external-css-file-using-jquery-javascript)

Comment: @lomboboo I was thinking about Javascript because I have a lot of classes with same syntax (like `bg-{color}`) and generating them automatically helps a lot. Due to your recommendation, I checked both SASS and LESS and found ways in both to generate classes, so I'm going to use SASS. Many Thanks!

Comment: @charlietfl In some websites that analyze SEO, inline-css is considered a bad practice. After you said, I checked and it seems I was wrong (You're right.), however, it makes the file messy.

Comment: Nothing in the source file if you use script to modify inline style