# how to trim dot at the end of string in JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string

How can I trim the dot at the end of string in JS ?

Input:

```
const string = 'ABCD.txt'
```

Output:

```
const string = 'ABCD'
```

How can I do ?

Thanks for help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568921/how-to-remove-part-of-a-string).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to trim a file extension from a String in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250364/how-to-trim-a-file-extension-from-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const string  = "ABCD.txt";
const result =  string.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const index = string.lastIndexOf('.');

const before = string.slice(0, index);
```